Getting error after login
I have restored master db from prod to local. Updated the connection string, but after I login, I see the below error. I have tried comparing my local's file with vanilla and even the one in prod.


Sitecore version 9.2
Here is the full stack:



Update 1:
After commenting scheduler related agents, I am getting the below error.

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]


   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.ResolvePathRec(String[] path, PathCache cache, CallContext context) +238
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.ResolvePathRec(String[] path, PathCache cache, CallContext context) +620
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.ResolvePathRec(String[] path, PathCache cache, CallContext context) +620
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.ResolvePath(String itemPath, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers) +135
   Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.ResolvePathCommand.‌‫⁫‬‬‮‌⁯⁬‏‍‫⁫‪‪⁮‪⁫‫⁭‪⁭⁯‭⁪‍⁬‬‪‭⁭‭⁪‫​⁬⁪⁭‬‮(String , Database ) +483
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +92
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck) +148


   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetLanguageFallbackItem.Process(GetItemArgs args) +177
   (Object , Object ) +13
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +501
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck) +304
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database) +146
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database) +153
   Sitecore.Globalization.DictionaryDomain.GetDomainDefinitionItem(Database database, String name) +183
   Sitecore.Globalization.DictionaryDomain.TryParse(String domainDefinition, Database database, DictionaryDomain& domain) +415
   Sitecore.Globalization.DictionaryDomain.GetDefaultDomain(Database database) +133
   

Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromContextDatabase.Process(GetTranslationArgs args) +148
   (Object , Object ) +8
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +501
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +235
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists) +35
   Sitecore.Globalization.DefaultTranslate.TextByLanguage(String domainName, TranslateOptions options, String key, Language language, String defaultValue, Object[] parameters) +336
   Sitecore.Globalization.DefaultTranslate.TextByLanguage(String key, Language language, String defaultValue, Object[] parameters) +89
   Sitecore.Globalization.DefaultTranslate.TextByLanguage(String key, Language language, String defaultValue) +90
   Sitecore.Globalization.DefaultTranslate.TextByLanguage(String key, Language language) +79
   Sitecore.Web.GlobalizationHost.Translate(String text) +66
   

ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_Layouts_Renderings_Authentications_AccountInformation_AccountInformation_cshtml.Execute() +375
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +251
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +147
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +121
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +135
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +274



[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/Layouts/Renderings/Authentications/AccountInformation/AccountInformation.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +747
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   


Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +502
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
  

 Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +214
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +502
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer) +250
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +61
   

ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_Layouts_Renderings_Structures_Substructures_GlobalHeader_cshtml.Execute() +502
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +275

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/Layouts/Renderings/Structures/Substructures/GlobalHeader.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +747
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
  
 Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +502
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195

   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +214
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +502
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer) +250
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +61
   
ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_Layouts_Renderings_Structures_Page_Structures_Application_Dashboard_cshtml.Execute() +195
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +275

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/Layouts/Renderings/Structures/Page Structures/Application/Dashboard.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +747
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +502
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   
Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +214
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +502
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer) +250
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +61
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute() +671
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +275

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +747
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   
Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +502
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +297
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +843
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +843
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I was able to resolve the error by closely monitoring the backup restore and also checking event logs in my system and even after around 10 GB space, the restore required some more temporary space which resulted in the backup restore kept getting failed or stuck in some process. I tried the same process on a virtual machine and I was able to see the SSMS backup restore's success message and tried with updating the connection string and I was able to see the master data on my local.
Thanks all for your assistance and kudos to this lovely forum, its definitely as ray of hope for those who are stuck :)

From the Stack trace it mentions that the schedule root item is missing in your master database.


There would be different Scheduled tasks defined in your config files which runs from master database. Could you please check what is the value of schedule root in each of the tasks and check if it exists.
Below are examples of some of them
<agent name="Master_Database_Agent" type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00" patch:source="Sitecore.Processing.config">
<param desc="database">master</param>
<param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
<LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>

<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" hint="EXM instance tasks" interval="00:00:59" patch:source="Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentManagementPrimary.config">
<param desc="database">master</param>
<param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/Settings/Email/instance tasks/content management primary</param>
<LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>

There might be some cutom scheduled tasks for which the item does not exists.
Hope this helps!!!

Tried searching with 'desc="schedule root"' in app config folder, found one extra entry in addition to above two entries..I have commented it..and reloaded the site..but I still see the same error about "GetAllSchedulesUnderRoot()"

Can you check in showconfig?

I am now trying to comment remaining entries and see if it resolves the error

I have added the new error in the update, although its still a object reference error, but end part about AccountInformation.cshtml is not present in my local.

This should be because of your dlls might have got mixed up. You need to compare the dlls and resolve the issue

I downloaded the dlls from prod, and replaced the one from my vanilla backup.

I have just checked old releases and the file AccountInformation.cshtml has not been part of the vanilla fileset since Sitecore 8.2 Update 7.
In your question, you have stated that you are running on Sitecore 9.2.
It looks like you have taken the database and a small subset of files from the old 8.2 installation and added them to a vanilla 9.2 release.
Unfortunately, I dont think there is any quick solution to get your site up and running without following the specific upgrade path from 8.2=>9.2. This involves changes to (all) files and databases.
Please see this "Upgrade Guide" at link for information on how to upgrade sitecore: https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update7

is it possible that old 8.2 files are in DB only...as I change back my connection string to vanilla..the site loads up..otherwise..it gives me error of missing files.

Yes - although it would be more likely the CORE database that would have the configutration linking to that old component.
