Error after backup restore
I am getting below error when I try to run the site after the web backup restore:


ManagedPoolThread #5 15:57:18 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )


11376 15:57:21 ERROR Application error.
    
**Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException**
    
**Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.**

Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
  

Nested Exception   

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent, String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric)
   at Sitecore.Shell.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Nested Exception   

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent, String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.DucatShell_a_238.Initialize()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl..ctor()

Nested Exception    

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent, String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.Shell_a_239.Initialize()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl..ctor()

Nested Exception   

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent, String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FormPage_a_240.Initialize()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl..ctor()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FormPage_a_240..ctor()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(Object obj, PropertyInfo property, Object value)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(Object obj, String name, Object value)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.SetProperties(Control control, Object[] properties)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl.AddControl(Control control, Control parent, String placeholderID, String[] properties)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.WebPanel_a_241.Initialize()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl..ctor()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.ResolvePathRec(String[] path, PathCache cache, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.ResolvePathRec(String[] path, PathCache cache, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.ResolvePathRec(String[] path, PathCache cache, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.ResolvePath(String itemPath, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.ResolvePathCommand.‌‫⁫‬‬‮‌⁯⁬‏‍‫⁫‪‪⁮‪⁫‫⁭‪⁭⁯‭⁪‍⁬‬‪‭⁭‭⁪‫​⁬⁪⁭‬‮(String , Database )
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetLanguageFallbackItem.Process(GetItemArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.DictionaryDomain.GetDomainDefinitionItem(Database database, String name)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.DictionaryDomain.TryParse(String domainDefinition, Database database, DictionaryDomain& domain)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.DictionaryDomain.GetDefaultDomain(Database database)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromContextDatabase.Process(GetTranslationArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.DefaultTranslate.TextByLanguage(String domainName, TranslateOptions options, String key, Language language, String defaultValue, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.DefaultTranslate.TextByLanguage(String key, Language language, String defaultValue, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.DefaultTranslate.TextByLanguage(String key, Language language, String defaultValue)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.DefaultTranslate.TextByLanguage(String key, Language language)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Literal.set_Text(String value)


Looks like the same problem you reported here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/37787/getting-error-after-login
Unless you have now completed the correct upgrade process? Both images (why still not text?) show the same first line in stacktrace.
